# How to return specific year from Date array ? react

Tags: javascript

I've got a dates array and I wanted to create a function that returns all the dates from 2014 or 2015 depending on what the user clicks

i tried using substring(), although that gives me an array of the 2014 dates, it also returns 2 undefined's which I dont want. How would I return an array of only 2014 dates?

```js
const datefunc = () => {
  const date = ['2014-4-4', '2014-5-4', '2015-4-4', '2015-3-4']

  const dates = date.map((d) => {
    if (d.substring(0, 4) === '2014') {
      return d;
    }
  })

  console.log(dates)
}

datefunc()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.map` modifies each element in an array => when you run `date.map` and only return a value if the date starts with '2014', all the other values in the array will become undefined.

`Array.filter` filters the elements in an array based on a predicate => when running `date.filter`, all the elements for which the predicate is false will be excluded in the returned array.

Changing your code to this should work:

```js
const datefunc = () => {
  const date = ['2014-4-4', '2014-5-4', '2015-4-4', '2015-3-4'];

  const dates = date.filter((d) => d.substring(0, 4) === '2014');

  // You could also use this
  // const dates = date.filter((d) => d.startsWith('2014'));

  console.log(dates);
  
}

datefunc();
```

If your dates aren't all of the same form, but all valid date strings you could also tranfsorm them into Date values and then filter them like this:

```js
const datefunc = () => {
  const date = ['2014-4-4', '2014-5-4', '2015-4-4', '2015-3-4'];

  const dates = date
    .map((d) => new Date(d))
    .filter((d) => d.getFullYear() === 2014);

  console.log(dates);
}

datefunc();
```

Comment: thank u so much! all this time I was using the wrong array method wow

Comment: how would I filter out by month? is there a more elegant way of doing it?

Comment: If you convert the stirngs to Date values, you can use date.getMonth()...beware though the month numbers start with 0 (= January)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const datefunc = () => {
  const date = ['2014-4-4', '2014-5-4', '2015-4-4', '2015-3-4']

  const dates = date.filter((d) => d.substring(0, 4) === '2014')

  console.log(dates)
}

datefunc()
```

Answer (score 1):

A more robust way to do this would be to convert string to date. Also, since you need to filter out dates, `map` wouldn't really work here. Even for false conditions, even though you are not returning anything, you end up returning `undefined` anyways. That's why those two undefined values

```js
const datefunc = () => {
  const date = ['2014-4-4', '2014-5-4', '2015-4-4', '2015-3-4']
  const targetYears = [2014, 2015]; // Add the years here which you want to filter on
  const dates = date.filter((d) => {
    const curYear = new Date(d).getFullYear();
    return targetYears.includes(curYear);
  })

  console.log(dates)
}

datefunc()
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const datesInYear = (dates, year) => {
  return dates.filter((x) => x.includes(year));
};

const dates = ["2014-4-4", "2014-5-4", "2015-4-4", "2015-3-4"];
console.log(datesInYear(dates, "2014"));
```

Comment: This `dates.filter(x => x.includes(year)` is invalid syntax!

Comment: Dear stack overflow society - why this answer have -2 points? - it's resolving the problem in efficient declarative manner?

Comment: There is nothing to do with react in this question?!

Comment: ok - thanks for explanation - but also the line ->  can be used in js.

        
      const datesInYear = (dates, year) => {
        return dates.filter(x => x.includes(year))
    }

Comment: Yes, because react is a javascript library... why add irrelevant things in the answer. Also, you should make a snippet of code whenever possible rather than adding it simply. For now, I am adding it.

Comment: how would I filter out by month? is there a more elegant way of doing it?

Comment: It’s depends on Your months format - in this solution You Can just pass „-2-„ for february and it will work

Answer (score -1):

You can add the years you want in the `filteredYears` array

```js
const datefunc = () => {
  const dates = ['2014-4-4', '2014-5-4', '2015-4-4', '2015-3-4']
  const filteredYears = [2014];
  const filteredDates = dates.filter(date => filteredYears.includes(new Date(date).getFullYear()));

  console.log(filteredDates)
}

datefunc()
```

Comment: Does this answers the questions?

Answer (score -1):

You may convert datestring to date type first, then make use "filter()" to get particular year date. Hopefully this helps you!

```
date = ["2014-4-4", "2014-5-4", "2015-4-4", "2015-3-4"];
convertedDate: Date[] = [];

getYearList() {
    this.date.forEach(x => {
      this.convertedDate.push(new Date(x));
    });

    this.convertedDate = this.convertedDate.filter(
      x => x.getFullYear() == 2014
    );
    console.log(this.convertedDate);
}
```

Comment: You function seems unnecessarily complex, also you use `this` even though you are not providing the context